# Why is my statement always false? if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='IPN_Handler')

Tags: php, get

I wrote an IPN listener for PayPal and when I first did it everything worked fine. I am not sure why, it stopped working. My Instant Payment Notification is set to: https://domainname/webpage/?action=IPN_Handler

Auto return for website payments url is: https://domainname/webpage

My Listener code is:

```
if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='IPN_Handler') {
    echo "Thank you for your payment";
    $amt = $_GET['amt'];
    $txn_id = $_GET['tx'];
    $st = $_GET['st'];
    $msg = $_GET['item_name'];
    $date= date("Y-m-d");
   }
```

Once the code returns the page has this in the location area:
[Link](https://domainname/webpage/?amt=0.01&cc=USD&item_name=Subscription%20-%20214&st=Completed&tx=6PK91382LD487075H)

I added a `var_dum`p on the if statement and it returns `bool(false)`.

What am I doing wrong with my code?

Comment: Open to sql injection use prepared statement https://www.php.net/manual/tr/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Forgive me but I have to ask @BigUncleE How comes you are geting private informations with that code, without security ? Sorry

Comment: `isset` use `true` and `&&` use `AND` . upgrade that code and it will work. try `print $_GET['action']`

Comment: @Dilek working on changing my code to prevent sql injection. All of the data in the code was actually changed. None of it is valid. After your comment I removed the sql portion.

Comment: @BigUncleE thanks for hearing me give me a litle time to give you an example

Comment: @BigUncleE Here is a simple prepare statement example with mysqli OOP way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for hearing me, Let me explain you how to upgrade prepare statement espacily in a payment process.
I dont have all your data so I will do it with what you showed in question.

Here is a simple prepare statement, hope it will help you.

`$conn` is db connection field change it to yours

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=='IPN_Handler') { 
// we get all params from html form I use post method always if dont need to get a url paratemer
    $amt = htmlspecialchars($_POST['amt']);
    $txn_id = htmlspecialchars($_POST['tx']);
    $st = htmlspecialchars($_POST['st']);
    $msg = htmlspecialchars($_POST['item_name']);
    $date= date("Y-m-d");

//Here we need to validate form inputs
    if(empty($amt) || empty($txn_id) || empty($st) || empty($msg)) { 
        echo "Field all required";
    }else{

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Your_table_name (amt, tx, st, item_name, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $amt, $txn_id, $st, $msg, $date);
         // we used bind_param so now we need to execute 
        if($stmt->execute()){
            echo "New records created successfully";
            header('Location: yourpage.php');
            exit();
        }else{
            echo "Failed to insert new records in database.";
        }

        // Free yourconnection
        $stmt->free_result();
    }
}
```

UPDATE :
Tested working on my case here is html form :

```html
<form action="page.php" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="amt" placeholder="dsdsd">
 <input type="text" name="tx" placeholder="sdsd">
 <input type="text" name="st" placeholder="dsdsd">
 <input type="text" name="item_name" placeholder="sdsd">
 <input type="text" name="date" placeholder="dsdsd">
 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="IPN_Handler" />
 <input type="submit" name="LoginBtn" placeholder="signup">
</form>
```

For more explanition see here https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Here is where I modified your code:

```
if (isset($_GET['action']) AND $_GET['action']=='IPN_Handler') {

//Here we need to validate form inputs
  $amt = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['amt']);
  $txn_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['tx']);
  $st = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['st']);
  $msg = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['item_name']);
  $date= date("Y-m-d");

    $sql = "UPDATE wp_ready2_play SET amount=?, payment_id=?, payment_status=?, message=?,  payment_dte=? WHERE id =?";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        echo "SQL error";
    } else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssss", $amt, $txn_id, $st, $msg, $date, $data);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        echo "Thank you for your payment";
        echo "Transaction has been made successfully.";
    }   
    // Free yourconnection
    mysqli_free_result($stmt);

}
```

Comment: Yes, this helped me immensely. Unfortunately, I am still investigating why the if statement is still false.

Comment: which if statement ? `if this if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=='IPN_Handler') {`  CHANGE it to :`if (isset($_POST['action'])) { ` and Change html form to `method=POST`.

Comment: This is not actually a button, it is waiting for Paypal to send the information back to the wepage.

Comment: IPN_Handler ? you can check for  the IPN_Handler on query success, in an if statement instead in form check. `if($_POST['IPN_Handler'] == paypal_result){ return page or display success}else{Not success}`

Comment: When I ran the code again using the PayPal Sandbox, I got the IPN_Handler in the response from PayPal. However, the if statement "(isset($_POST['action']) AND $_POST['action']=='IPN_Handler')" is still False. I have more research to do.

Comment: @BigUncleE I know nothing about paypal some others can help you, I just seen a tutorial IPN_Handler is coming from url like : https://yourwebsite.com/index.php?page=cart&ipn_handler=paypal if yours is the same and coming from url ? you need to change $_POST method to $_GET methods, HERE : `if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=='IPN_Handler') {` Let me know for response. This tutorial : https://codeshack.io/how-to-integrate-paypal-php-mysql/ probably changing post method will solve your problem

Comment: @BigUncleE I tested code working on my case, if still not working on your case then you need to see this answer for separeting pages : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25934880/expresscheckout-ipn-invalid-response-status-403?rq=1

Comment: Everything is fine now. I had to modify your code a little.

Comment: @BigUncleE Nice, glad I helped a litle and wested your time :)

Comment: Not a waste. You're a Great Teacher.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is always false because... the statement is always false. Look at the query string:

```
?amt=0.01&cc=USD&item_name=Subscription%20-%20214&st=Completed&tx=6PK91382LD487075H
```

There is no `action` item set anywhere, so the code execution correctly skips the block. You need to actually pass in the action, and it's associated value *somehow* for the code to execute like you expect.

The easiest, lowest-effort way of doing this is to simply add a hidden input inside the form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="IPN_Handler" />
```

When you submit the form, you should then see the new query string include the action parameter with the specified value, as `action=IPN_Handler`. You should be careful to verify the action value though, as users can manipulate hidden inputs simply by opening the developer tools.

Comment: The code worked in the beginning. I am investigating the information you posted.

Comment: I added some more info, let me know if it helps

Comment: You were correct with your initial comment about the statement always being false. When I did the test again using PayPal Sandbox it had this in the reply: https://domainname/webpage/?action=IPN_Handler .  Sandbox still does not work. So, I have more research to do.