# Paypal donation return url is giving an empty array

Tags: php, paypal

I have been trying to implement paypal donation in my site. The usual form is okay, working fine. But I wanted add a return url where the paypal returns after successfully donations. The paypal returning to that page successfully but I can not get any data of the donation details in return url. Here is the code I wrote for the donation form:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="myEmail@gmail.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost/thankyou.php" id="paypal_return">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://test.org/ipn_route_for_payment" id="ipn_url">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" title="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" alt="Donate with PayPal button" />
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" />
</form>
```

And the following code I wrote in return url:

```
<?php 
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

I tried with both request and post method but did not get any data. But I am getting IPN notifications.

**Note: I tried with live payment too**

Comment: See this answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/59554603/12232340

Comment: Thanks for the link but did not get my answer yet

Comment: AFAIK the return URL doesn’t get any data POSTed to it; PayPal will just append the transaction ID as a GET parameter named `tx`. An actual POST request back to your system would happen under the `notify_url`, in the background.

Comment: You can’t get response from PayPal with html you showed in question, that form only post inputs you fill in the form, you need some php codes to get response from PayPal, check the link I gave once again, and edit your question add your full php codes in question and show us how do you get response from PayPal.

Comment: If I use <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick " />  instead of <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations " /> I get all the data in return url. Could you please explain why is it happening or how can I get response data in return url

Comment: It’s explained well in answer IPN vs PDT and `$_GET` instead of `$_POST` on return, all explained very well in documentation’s https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payment-data-transfer/ and the answer in the given link in my comment is complete solution for IPN. and is answer of your question.

Answer (score 0):

As comments have mentioned, [PDT uses a GET string](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payment-data-transfer/).

So you would want to make sure that is enabled, and then access the contents of $_GET

Please note that PDT is for informational purposes only. No return is *ever* guaranteed to happen after a Payments Standard transaction -- the buyer may be shown a receipt and need to click to return for example, or they may close their browser or have it crash.

Absolutely no business logic should be triggered by PDT; its only servicable purpose is to show a slightly more information "Thank you" / "Success" type message to the customer.

Any actual business logic needs to be triggered by an asynchronous IPN or webhook instead.

Comment: If I use <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick " />  instead of <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations " /> I get all the data in return url. Could you please explain why is it happening or how can I get response data in return url

Comment: Ahh, I wasn't aware that _donations behaved differently than _xclick in this respect! Well it basically seems PDT was not built to work with donations then, only commercial transactions. You will have to implement IPN or a webhook instead to get the data

Comment: Could you please have another look in the form where I already add ipn url. And I am getting IPN information. I do not have any issues with that. But I am not getting any kind of data in return url for donations. But for normal payment I got it