# Login to PayPal using CURL without using PayPal API

Tags: php, paypal, web-scraping

I want know,from where should I provide username, password credential [topher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854207/access-denied-on-paypal-ipn-verification/38764356#38764356)'s code...  I know it is some what silly question. I am not getting

`$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');`

how exactly works

Please help me...

Thanks in advance..  :)

Comment: Please don't edit your question into a different question. You can always ask a new question, but even your edited question lacks [minimal, complete code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `I want know,from where should I provide username, password credential "topher's" code` this was my main question @Machavity

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking this. I learned something new today.
This was answered [in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731297/file-get-contentsphp-input-or-http-raw-post-data-which-one-is-better-to). You are actually doing the same as reading `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` (wich is deprecated).

Usually when just submitting a basic form you want to read `$_POST` to get an array of elements php already splitted neatly for you:

```
$_POST = array(
"key1" => "value1",
"key2" => "value2",);
```

But when you actually need `key1=value1&key2=value2` you want to get the "raw post data". Thats what `file_get_contents('php://input');` does.
`file_gets_content` is usually intended to read a file (local file or url).