# Why does my PHP Discord Oauth2 Auth return nothing?

Tags: php, curl, discord

vv Post Request vv

```
        $code = $_GET['code'];
        $headers = [
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Accept: application/json",
        ];
        $data = <<<DATA
        {
            "grant_type": "authorization_code",
            "code": $code,
            "client_secret": $clientsecret,
            "client_id": $clientid
        }
        DATA;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token');
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNHEADERS,true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
        echo curl_exec($ch);
```

This code is supposed to return the auth code of a oauth2 auth;
`{ "access_token": "6qrZcUqja7812RVdnEKjpzOL4CvHBFG", }`

It's supposed to return that. Nothing is being returned on my post request.

Currently, I am trying to oauth2 authorize users in my discord server.
This isn't working, when I send the request and try to print it.
Nothing is returned. My secret client code and client ids are correct.
I don't know what the issue is. Can someone please help me with my issue?
*I have tried different ways of sending the request*
Needless to say, it still doesn't work.
Please someone help me. I am new with PHP and I don't fully understand all of the issues.

Comment: you might want to add the user agent in the cURL call: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17801135/188331

Comment: @Raptor why do I need to add an useragent?

Comment: @Raptor adding a useragent doesn't work

Comment: Does it work in [Postman](https://www.postman.com/)?

Comment: @JMP I cant find it on postman

Comment: Some APIs require a user agent string to work. Your "doesn't work" means the API still return nothing? have you turned on error reporting by adding `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the first line?

Comment: You haven't specified a Redirect: (from Discord) Redirects
You must specify at least one URI for authentication to work. If you pass a URI in an OAuth request, it must exactly match one of the URIs you enter here.

Comment: @JMP I have specified an URI, and it still doesn't work

Comment: @Raptor I have it on my first line and there is no errors reported

Comment: Redirects are usually in the DATA section, e.g. "redirect_uri:https://www.example.com/login.php"

Comment: @JMP `{
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "code": $code,
        "client_secret": $clientsecret,
        "client_id": $clientid,
        'redirect_uri':"condo.aero-dev.xyz/index.php"
    }` is my data section atm

Comment: The redirect_uri is where users get sent after they auth your app, and should receive and then process the access token. Are your quotes correct?

Comment: @JMP the quotes are correct

Comment: Turns out that my host had completely blocked the discord api for some reason

Answer (score 0):

JSON data is not supported on this endpoint, try "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"... Also you're missing the redirect URL