# optimize foreach loop php

Tags: php, curl, optimization, fopen

I've got double foreach loop. Script takes urls from one file and tries to find it in html code of pages from another file. Of course that reading so many pages is pretty hard for server so I want to optimize script but how can I do it?

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$sites_raw = file('https://earnmoneysafe.com/script/sites.txt');
$sites = array_map('trim', $sites_raw);
$urls_raw = file('https://earnmoneysafe.com/script/4toiskatj.txt');
$urls = array_map('trim', $urls_raw);

function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $config['useragent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0';

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $config['useragent']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

foreach ($sites as $site){
    $homepage = file_get_contents_curl($site);
    foreach ($urls as $url){
        $needle   = $url;
        if (strpos($homepage, $needle) !== false) {
            echo 'true';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You could use `curl_multi_exec()` to fetch all the URLs in parallel.

Comment: FYI, if you're using `trim()` to remove the newlines, you can do that automatically with the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag to the `file()` function.

Comment: @Barmar I'm newbie with cUrl. I tried to do it with cUrl but got 403 from every page

Comment: I can't see why the same request would return an error from `curl` but would work with `file_get_contents()`. Did you use the same user agent? Post your curl attempt.

Comment: @Barmar posted cUrl attempt

Comment: You probably need to set the user agent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17801094/php-curl-how-to-add-the-user-agent-value-or-overcome-the-servers-blocking-curl-r

Comment: @Barmar yeah, problem was with user agent but some url still are not avaliable such as https://www.si.com/showcase/nutrition/best-weight-loss-programs

Comment: Different sites use different techniques to prevent web scraping. They might be using a cookie.

Comment: @Barmar OK. So I edited the code (change `file_get_contents()` to cUrl). But script still is too slow and gives `Request Timeout` error. How can I use `curl_multi_exec()`? Can you write  an answer please?

Answer (score 1):

Use `curl_multi_exec()` to fetch all the URLs in parallel.

```
$urls = file('https://earnmoneysafe.com/script/4toiskatj.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$sites = file('https://earnmoneysafe.com/script/sites.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach ($sites as $site) {
    $curl_handles[$site] = get_curl($site);
}
$mh = curl_multi_init();
foreach ($curl_handles as $ch) {
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
}

do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

foreach ($curl_handles as $site => $ch) {
    $homepage = curl_multi_getcontent($ch);
    foreach ($urls as $needle) {
        if (strpos($homepage, $needle) !== false) {
            echo 'true';
        }
    }
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
}

curl_multi_close($mh);
    
function get_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $config['useragent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $config['useragent']); // edited  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       

    return $ch;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. But where should I put Urls which I have to find in these pages. In original code I had `$urls_raw = file('https://earnmoneysafe.com/script/4toiskatj.txt');`

Comment: Sorry, I confused `$sites` and `$urls`.

Comment: I added that to the answer.

Comment: I cannot see results though some sites have urls from that file. For example `https://www.golo.com/` has `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js` in it's code

Comment: `echo $homepage` returns null. Something is wrong with the code

Comment: If `$homepage` is null, use [`curl_multi_errno()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-errno.php) to get the error code.

Comment: I should paste `echo curl_multi_errno();` in `foreach ($curl_handles as $site => $ch) {` loop?

Comment: You only need to do that if `$homepage` is null. `if ($homepage === null) { echo "Error: " . curl_multi_errno($ch); }`

Comment: It didn't show anything. `curl_multi_errno($ch)` is null too

Answer (score 0):

I think this, This code is cleaner

```
<?php

const SITES_URL = 'https://earnmoneysafe.com/script/sites.txt';
const URLS_URL = 'https://earnmoneysafe.com/script/4toiskatj.txt';

function readFileLines($url) {
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($url);
    $lines = explode("\n", $file_contents);
    $filtered_lines = array_filter($lines, function($line) {
        return !empty(trim($line));
    });

    return $filtered_lines;
}

function checkSiteUrls($site, $urls) {
    $homepage = file_get_contents($site);
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        if (strpos($homepage, $url) !== false) {
            echo 'true';
        }
    }
}

$sites = readFileLines(SITES_URL);
$urls = readFileLines(URLS_URL);

foreach ($sites as $site) {
    checkSiteUrls($site, $urls);
}

?>
```